# box-java-sdk - Normal Authentication

Tags: java, authentication, box

I am trying to build an application with Box SDK in Java. Currently, I am connecting to my Box with a developer token:

```
BoxAPIConnection api = new BoxAPIConnection("MY-DEVELOPER-TOKEN");
```

I have to generate a new developer token every 60 minutes, therefore I would like to make it so this is done automatically. According to the [Box API authentication doc](https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk/blob/master/doc/authentication.md), we can do it with:

```
BoxAPIConnection api = new BoxAPIConnection("MY-CLIENT-ID", "MY-CLIENT-SECRET", "MY-AUTH-CODE");
```

However, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.box.sdk.BoxAPIException: The API returned an error code: 400
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Auth code doesn't exist or is invalid for the client"}
```

I get my Client ID and Client Secret from the configuration page of my Box account, so I assume these are correct. Where can I get my authentication code? The one I am using is the one from a pop-up window when I first connected to my account.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the authentication code like this:

1. go to a browser and type in with your client_id:

https://account.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxx&state&state=security_token%3DKnhMJatFipTAnM0nHlZA

2. authorize the app and you'll get a code back (make sure your redirect is something like localhost
3. then use postman and do this (fill in the code w/ what you just got back)

[image]